# Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript

the run results is ok,but I don't know why come out this mistake.thanks.
 the browser is Chrome.
 Error:Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 
 'checked' of null. at Object.SL_BBL_locer

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
            window.addEventListener('message',function(e){
                var color=e.data;
                console.log(color);
            },false);
            window.frames[0].postMessage('getcolor','http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/onMessage.jsp');
        }
    </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
            <iframe id="child" src="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/onMessage.jsp"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there any more js code? Probably you are setting a variable equal to a dom element that doesn't exist.

Comment: onMessage.jsp:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
 window.addEventListener('message',function(e){
     if(e.source!=window.parent) return;
     var color = 'green';
     window.parent.postMessage(color,'*');
 },false);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: the error only exists in Chrome

Comment: the error is Chrome，thank you for your answer sincerely